# Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks

Tags: paypal, webhooks

I'm attempting to use the PaypalWebHookHandler in an mvc application that uses the nuget package: Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Paypal

When i use the Paypal Webhook Simulator with the following url:

https:///api/webhooks/incoming/paypal

I'm getting the following two debug lines in my Visual Studio:

> w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Processing incoming WebHook request with receiver 'paypal' and id ''.
>   w3wp.exe Error: 0 : The received WebHook is not valid.

The `public override Task ExecuteAsync(string receiver, WebHookHandlerContext context)` event is not being called.

This is my 1st stackoverflow question, so i'm sorry if its poorly written.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Comment: any suggestions would be still welcome.